# Curl Windows / Linux

Tags: curl, cypress

From Cypress, I need to push 2 PDF files to a server. So I chose Curl to do this from a cy.exec().
Currently my request goes very well on my development workstation (Windows) but the same request does not go through at all on my CI (unix).
I tested a lot of things but I can't get my Curl request to execute correctly from the CI;

Here is the request executed via the cy.exec()

```
curl -X POST http://url/api/acme/test --user "user:acme!" --basic -H "content-type: multipart/form-data;" -F "file1=@cypress/downloads/file.pdf" -F "file2=@cypress/downloads/file.pdf" -F "profile=profil" -F "name=filename"
```

How I create my call

```
 const post =   "curl -X POST \
  " + Cypress.env('url') + "acme"+ " \
  --user \""+ Cypress.env('user') +":"+ Cypress.env('pwd') +"\" \
  --basic -H \"content-type: multipart/form-data;\" \
   -F \"file1=@"+ file1 +"\" \
   -F \"file2=@"+ file2 +"\" \
   -F \"profile="+ filtre +"\" \
   -F \"name="+ fichierTest +"\" ";
```

If anyone has any idea, thanks in advance

Comment: You say it "doesn't go through" - what actually happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: If you're using Cypress, why not use `cy.request()` to handle this? https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Syntax